# Microsoft python language server doesn't stop downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I know this question might already be asked but I have a serious problem with this
every time when I open my vscode and I want to code in python it shows me that Microsoft python language server is downloading and when I have no stable connection it will stack and I can't even code in python

what should I do?
I want this to stop downloading!

Comment: use idle or  simply use vs code for editing and use vs code built in terminal for execution

Comment: VS Code always downloads Python Server to see if any updates and it needs to be installed everytime. Without Python Server, you will not be able to use its intellisense features and you will be able to code. I would recommend to reload the window and to download python server it takes few minutes and its not too big, I mean even your 5 minute mobile hotspot will support the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"` to stop VS Code from trying to download the Microsoft language server.